# Why is my MySQL procedure that's supposed to select a random row only selecting one of three specific values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored MySQL procedure called `quote_of_the_day` that is supposed to select a different row from the `quotes` table each day, using the date as the seed value. When I test the code as a query, everything appears to run fine, BUT when I call the function in my php code (query is `CALL quote_of_the_day()`) it only ever selects one of three different quotes, despite the fact that there are 23 quotes in the table.

The create systax for `quote_of_the_day` is:

```sql
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `quote_of_the_day`()
BEGIN
        # save the number of rows into a variable
        SET @num_rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `quotes`);

        # calculate a random number no greater than the number of rows in the table
        SET @rand_num = (SELECT FLOOR(RAND(CURDATE())*(@num_rows+1)));

        # select random quote from the list of quotes (seed value is the current day)
        SELECT quote FROM quotes WHERE id = @rand_num;
        
        # increment the quoted column to keep track of which quotes are selected
        UPDATE quotes SET quoted = quoted + 1 WHERE id = @rand_num AND last_used <> CURDATE();
        UPDATE quotes SET last_used = CURDATE() WHERE id = @rand_num;
    END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why the curdate that gives back always teh same number so delete it

Comment: @nbk, wait for tomorrow, then it will return another value.... 

Comment: your alghorithm will never work to select a random number

Answer (score 1):

The comments above are teasing you with the answer.

Read the manual on MySQL's [RAND() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> ...for equal argument values, RAND(N) returns the same value each time, and thus produces a repeatable sequence of column values. In the following example, the sequence of values produced by RAND(3) is the same both places it occurs.

Since CURDATE() returns a constant value every time you call it within the same day, passing it to RAND() makes RAND() return the same value every time you call it.

Demo:

```
mysql> select rand(curdate());
+------------------+
| rand(curdate())  |
+------------------+
| 0.49455075570806 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rand(curdate());
+------------------+
| rand(curdate())  |
+------------------+
| 0.49455075570806 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rand(curdate());
+------------------+
| rand(curdate())  |
+------------------+
| 0.49455075570806 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rand(curdate());
+------------------+
| rand(curdate())  |
+------------------+
| 0.49455075570806 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will continue until my clock says it's a new day.

You don't actually need to pass a value to seed RAND(). It gets a seed when the MySQL server starts, and continues to generate random values.

Don't use the seed argument when you want a series of new random values, use the seed argument when you want a *reproducible series of random values*, for example if you're running automated tests.

---

Re your comment:

The argument to RAND() is an integer, but dates like '2021-11-07' are returned as a string. In a numeric context, the integer value of '2021-11-07' is 2021. Any non-numeric characters are stripped off before passing it as the argument to RAND().

```
mysql> select rand('2021-11-04');
+--------------------+
| rand('2021-11-04') |
+--------------------+
| 0.7752841103591808 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rand('2021-11-05');
+--------------------+
| rand('2021-11-05') |
+--------------------+
| 0.7752841103591808 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rand('2021-11-06');
+--------------------+
| rand('2021-11-06') |
+--------------------+
| 0.7752841103591808 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rand('2021-11-07');
+--------------------+
| rand('2021-11-07') |
+--------------------+
| 0.7752841103591808 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

You can see that it's doing this:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '2021-11-07' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

All these dates are seeding the randomizer as if you had passed only '2021' or 2021 as the argument:

```
mysql> select rand('2021');
+--------------------+
| rand('2021')       |
+--------------------+
| 0.7752841103591808 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rand(2021);
+--------------------+
| rand(2021)         |
+--------------------+
| 0.7752841103591808 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: But shouldn't I still get a different value every day? Since the seed value (the current date) is different? It's been running for a bit over a week now, but has only selected three different quotes, each three different times.

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: But if that's true, then shouldn't it be selecting the same value each time? It's thus far selected 3 different quotes. If the seed is indeed 2021 each time, shouldn't it always get the same quote?

Comment: You must have passed a different value to RAND(), or else no argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your seed is constant to for the year of the date because when MySQL converts strings to dates it uses the first string of digits it finds in the string, which is currently `2021`.

Use [`TO_DAYS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) Seed `RAND()` with the number of days since year `0`:

```
RAND(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()))
```

Every day will forever pass a different, but constant for the current date, value to `rand()`

Comment: If that's true, shouldn't it be returning the same quote every day of 2021?

Comment: @just_another_question No. `TO_DAYS(CURDATE())` returns the number of days between year 0 and today's *date*, not today's *year*. For every day that goes by,  `TO_DAYS(CURDATE())` returns a result `1` greater than it did the day before. See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/253714).